# Developing complex product to derive identity

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm referring to this question : [Finding a trigonometric polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316436/finding-a-trigonometric-polynomial)

The OP says :

> On the unit circle $$f(\theta) = F(e^{i\theta}) = c \prod_{j=1}^n\frac{(e^{i\theta}-\beta_j)(1-\overline\beta_j e^{i\theta})}{(e^{i\theta}-\gamma_j)(1-\overline\gamma_j e^{i\theta})}$$
>   The terms in the product simplify to
>   $$\left| \frac{e^{i\theta} - \beta_j}{e^{i\theta} - \gamma_j} \right|^2$$

I've developed the terms in the product but it's not obvious how to derive $\left| \frac{e^{i\theta} - \beta_j}{e^{i\theta} - \gamma_j} \right|^2$. A bit of help would be welcome. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice 
\begin{align*}
\frac{(e^{i\theta}-\beta_j)(1-\overline\beta_j e^{i\theta})}{(e^{i\theta}-\gamma_j)(1-\overline\gamma_j e^{i\theta})} & = \frac{e^{i\theta}(1-\beta_je^{-i\theta})(1-\overline\beta_j e^{i\theta})}{e^{i\theta}(1-\gamma_je^{-i\theta})(1-\overline\gamma_j e^{i\theta})}\\
& = \frac{(1-\beta_je^{-i\theta})\overline{(1-\beta_je^{-i\theta})}}{(1-\gamma_je^{-i\theta})\overline{(1-\gamma_je^{-i\theta})}} \\
& =\left| \frac{1-\beta_je^{-i\theta}}{1-\gamma_je^{-i\theta}} \right|^2\\
& =\left| \frac{e^{-i\theta}}{e^{-i\theta}} \right|^2 \left| \frac{e^{i\theta}-\beta_j}{e^{i\theta}-\gamma_j} \right|^2\\
& =\left| \frac{e^{i\theta}-\beta_j}{e^{i\theta}-\gamma_j} \right|^2.
\end{align*}